# Will there be only 1 static-nested class instance total for all the outer-class instances? Can only 1 instance occur without the singleton pattern?

Tags: java, listener, onclicklistener

I have been looking at different ways of making Listeners in Android. I encapsulated the listener in a separate class called `OperationClick.` I have also used the strategy pattern to encapsulate logic and that is interfaced with the `enum` type `BinaryOperator.` What I have is a simple calculator that you probably seen online already - 2 input numbers, 1 result, and 4 buttons (+, -, *, and /).

What I have seen is that I need to create 4 different listeners for the 4 buttons; however, I encapsulated the logic for each button so I only need 1 listener. The only problem is that I need to differentiate each listener with the correct logic (BinaryOperator: + - * /).

So what I will have is `4` buttons, `4` instances of `OperationClick`, but I don't know about the *static nested class* `Listener` (below the line of `******************` in the code).

**So my main question is...**

Will there be `1` instance of `Listener` because it is declared `static`, or will there be `4` instances?

I created `(nested) static class Listener` solely for the purpose that I would save from extra instantiations of the click listener... i.e. there would only be `1` instance of `Listener` for all the instances of `OperationClick`

**However, if my logic is wrong about there being only `1` instance of static nested `Listener` class,** then how can that be done without the Singleton pattern? I figured adding `static` to the class would do that, but I am not sure.

### MainActivity.java

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OperationClick(this, Add).getListener());
btnSub.setOnClickListener(new OperationClick(this, Subtract).getListener());
btnMul.setOnClickListener(new OperationClick(this, Multiply).getListener());
btnDiv.setOnClickListener(new OperationClick(this, Divide).getListener());
```

### OperationClick.java

```
public class OperationClick {

    private View.OnClickListener listener;

    public OperationClick(MainActivity activity, BinaryOperation operator) {

        this.listener = new Listener(activity, operator.getOperation());

    }

    public View.OnClickListener getListener() { return this.listener; }


****************************************************************************
    // Static Nested Class - Does this make only one instance of Listener even with multiple OperationClick instances?
    private static class Listener implements View.OnClickListener {

        MainActivity UI;
        Operation operation;

        public Listener(MainActivity activity, Operation operation) {

            this.UI = activity;
            this.operation = operation;

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            double total, num1, num2;

            num1 = Double.parseDouble(UI.txtNumber1.getText().toString());
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(UI.txtNumber2.getText().toString());

            total = operation.execute(num1, num2);

            UI.txtResult.setText(Double.toString(total));

        }
    }
}
```

### Operation.java (Context class in strategy pattern)

```
public class Operation {

    private IOperationStrategy strategy;

    public Operation(IOperationStrategy strategy) { this.strategy = strategy; }

    public double execute(double a, double b) { return this.strategy.executeOperation(a, b); }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you just declare `MainActivity` to implement `View.OnClickListener`? You then just set the listener as `this` (i.e., the `Activity` itself) and check in the `onClick(...)` method for which button has been clicked.

Comment: That seems to have issues of itself, but I might have answered my own question, because I would only have one instance of the listener, but it would not know what operation to perform at `operation.execute(num1, num2);`. This is because I need to have one instance for each operation; not one instance total.

Comment: What do you think @Squonk . How can I make sure variable `operation` calls the right method of `execute(...)` if I have MainActivity implement `View.OnClickListener`

Comment: It's not difficult... `public class MainActivity extends class implements View.OnClickListener {...}`. You then create a method as `public void onClick(View v) {...}`. In that method use `v.getId()` to identify the button that was clicked and use a `switch / case` block. All you have to do after that is set the listeners such as `btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this)` and so on. You're basically over thinking things and what I've just described is a common approach in Android.

Comment: Yeah, but I did have a switch statement before in my `OperationClick` class that dealt with that logic, but my `BinaryOperation` class abstracts away all that logic within the named instances. So that meant I could get rid of the switch statement altogether - which I actually prefer......However, it seems like your method would mean that I have to bring the switch statement back in another form via `v.getId()`. This is kind of undesirable

Comment: This isn't my final version, I am planning on changing it up, but just going incrementally right now to abstract away things, and clean up my code. I really hate the defacto android programming style. It is very messy and hard to read and understand what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

a nested static class still supports multiple instances.

the difference between using and not using the `static` keyword for your nested class is whether it has a hidden reference to the parent class.

the best way you can reduce unnecessary allocations is to get rid of the `Listener` class altogether and just have `OperationClick` implement `View.OnClickListener`.

as currently structured, your `Listener` class has an instance field of type `Operation` that is assigned on construction. if you only have one `Listener`, you will also only have one `Operation` handled by that listener, which is probably not what you intend. i'd discard this approach entirely.

Comment: OK, I edited the question slightly. How can I make sure only one instance occurs. I guess a singleton would do that, but I am wondering if there are simplier ways.

Comment: I completely see where you are coming from, just want to make sure with the strategy pattern's context class.

Comment: yeah my diagnosis hasn't changed - your `Listener` only has one `Operation` associated with it, so you need a new one for each `Operation` you're listening for.